# unexpected WAI Presentation_id

Tags: content-delivery, database

The following is configuration is done for WAI on the content delivery

```
<Presentations>
        <Presentation Id="1">
            <Host Domain="www.mysite.com" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/"/>
            ..... 
        </Presentation>
</Presentations>
```

In the Users table of the Broker database, there are records added with presentation_id -1.

With the configuration above I wouldn't expect presentation_id -1.
does any one has an explanation for this?

Comment: Assuming your domain name is correct, I would indeed not expect this. I think we log quite a bit of the process in DEBUG, worth taking a look at the logs...

Comment: I also has some records with the -1 in the User table, and I have found that I have some application errors in the Event Log, trying to access the odata.svc servide in the application. I don't know the relation, baut it seems to be some circunstantial errors

Answer (score 1):

Please check following configuration: and match with your configuration.

```
<Presentation Id="13">

            <Host Domain="dev.dxa.com" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/"/>
            <Personalization Enabled="true" Persistence="cookies">
                <!-- The Cookie element allows you to specify properties for cookies. -->               <Cookie Name="TDS1234567" Expires="39000"/>
```

- host is your CD website URL
- other information is for cookie.

Comment: The "presentation id" of the wai_conf doesn't have to match the "Publication id". They are different things.

Comment: Yes. agree! updated, i forgot to remove that line earlier.